# Generate all possible combinations where consecutive pairs can have a max difference of 1000

Tags: python, conditional-statements, combinations

I would like to generate combinations with length 9 out of a sorted list (length 150) without any repeated values:

> 24, 110, 157, 256, 278, 368, 416, 502, 593, 666, 751, 801, 827, 925,
>   991, 1044, 1118, 1159, 1203, 1296, 1375, 1479, 1546, 1621, 1679, 1695,
>   1726, 1832, 1922, 1978, 1995, 2041, 2119, 2160, 2240, 2315, 2421,
>   2493, 2527, 2543, 2559, 2654, 2762, 2813, 2883, 2950, 2982, 3009,
>   3052, 3103, 3162, 3239, 3346, 3427, 3462, 3480, 3548, 3638, 3670,
>   3761, 3833, 3898, 3946, 3979, 4051, 4096, 4124, 4219, 4289, 4393,
>   4455, 4497, 4590, 4695, 4769, 4835, 4874, 4891, 4965, 5065, 5159,
>   5247, 5323, 5352, 5406, 5493, 5534, 5581, 5687, 5796, 5881, 5982,
>   6049, 6110, 6200, 6266, 6297, 6312, 6392, 6452, 6501, 6599, 6651,
>   6734, 6758, 6799, 6859, 6912, 6942, 7049, 7149, 7258, 7296, 7317,
>   7363, 7446, 7494, 7589, 7653, 7737, 7803, 7820, 7929, 8012, 8117,
>   8135, 8174, 8242, 8349, 8417, 8511, 8589, 8611, 8643, 8717, 8765,
>   8795, 8854, 8880, 8936, 8987, 9041, 9100, 9186, 9292, 9398, 9472,
>   9502, 9598, 9642, 9731, 9789, 9864, 9936

I already tried it with:

```
itertools.combinations(list, 9)
```

However, that's not very efficient and would generate more than a billion combinations. I only want the combinations where the difference between each pair of consecutive numbers is 150 or less. For example, the combination

```
(24, 110, 157, 256, 278, 368, 416, 502, 593)
```

has no consecutive pairs with a difference greater than 150, but the combination

```
(24, 110, 157, 256, 278, 368, 416, 502, 9936)
```

has a consecutive pair `502, 9936` with a difference greater than 150.

How can I achieve this in Python? The input list is sorted and I need the output to be sorted as well.

---

I already found this solution, which was very good. However the output wasn't sorted which was my problem, and it generates combinations where every pair has a maximum difference of 150 - not just consecutive pairs - so it excludes the example given above because 593 - 24 > 150.

```
import itertools
import random

def combs(nums):
    result = set()
    for lower in nums:
        options = [n for n in nums if lower <= n <= lower + 150]
        result.update(itertools.combinations(options, 9))
    return result

print(combs([random.randrange(0, 5000) for _ in range(150)]))
```

Comment: Didn't you just ask this question a few hours ago? Please post one time per question. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate all possible combinations with a given condition to make it more efficient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59018910/how-to-generate-all-possible-combinations-with-a-given-condition-to-make-it-more)